No puele seleccionar item del combobox que se carga con tres columnas de mi bd
Asi cargo el Combo
Private Sub cargarcb2()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Nombre, Apellido, Id As String
    Try
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT Id, Nombre, Apellido FROM Clientes "
        Dim adt As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, configuracion.cnx)
        adt.Fill(ds)


        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

                Id = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Id")
                Nombre = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Nombre")
                Apellido = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Apellido")

                Combo2.Items.Add(Id & "-" & Nombre & "," & Apellido)

            Next

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

el combo se carga bien con los datos, pero necesito selecciona solo el id.
Y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo
Alguien prodia ayudarme

Si te sirve con ver sólo el nombre y los apellidos al desplegar el combo puedes probar a cargarlo como se indica aquí:
Como obtener el valor seleccionado de un ComboBox
Si tiene que ser como lo haces, para sacar sólo el ID se me ocurre que cortes la cadena que te devuelve: el id sería desde la primera posición hasta donde se encuentre el "-"
Espero que te sirva!
